# Matricial product of various matrices inside a list

Tags: r, matrix

How to calculate the product of all matrices (all matrices are nxn) inside of a list, for example,

```
a1 <- list(); a2 <- list(); a3 <- list()
a1[[1]] <- matrix(c(1:25), byrow = T, ncol = 5)
a1[[2]] <- matrix(c(1:25), byrow = T, ncol = 5)
a2[[1]] <- matrix(c(1:25), byrow = T, ncol = 5)
a2[[2]] <- matrix(c(1:25), byrow = T, ncol = 5)
a3[[1]] <- matrix(c(1:25), byrow = T, ncol = 5)
a3[[2]] <- matrix(c(1:25), byrow = T, ncol = 5)

a <- list(a1, a2, a3)

a1[[1]]%*%a1[[2]]%*%a2[[1]]%*%a1[[2]]%*%a3[[1]]%*%a3[[2]]
```

Comment: Your example gives me error.  Shouldn't `rnorm(25, ncol 5)` be `rnorm(25), ncol = 5)` also, the `a1[[1]]` is not clear.  Are there three `list` of length 1 or just a single `list` with 3 elements?

Comment: There are three `list`, but length can be greater one.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` for reproducibility and also show the expected output

Comment: I rewrote the question.

Comment: Did you meant `a1[[1]]%*%a1[[2]]%*%a2[[1]]%*%a2[[2]]%*%a3[[1]]%*%a3[[2]]`

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is elementwise product of three matrices inside a single `list`

```
Reduce(`*`, a)
```

If there are 3 `list`s of length 1.

```
a1 <- list(a1)
a2 <- list(a2)
a3 <- list(a3)
Map(function(...) Reduce(`*`, list(...)), a1, a2, a3)
```

#### Update

For the updated post,

```
r1 <- Reduce(`%*%`, do.call(c, list(a1, a2, a3)))
r2 <- a1[[1]]%*%a1[[2]]%*%a2[[1]]%*%a2[[2]]%*%a3[[1]]%*%a3[[2]]
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
a1 <- matrix(rnorm(25), ncol= 5)
a2 <- matrix(rnorm(25), ncol= 5)
a3 <- matrix(rnorm(25), ncol = 5)
a <- list(a1, a2, a3)
```

Comment: I need to calculate the matricial product, this form calculate the product elementwise product.

Comment: @WagnerJorge I commented in your post some half an hour ago, please change the mistakes in your post and also show an expected output

Comment: I rewrote the question.

Comment: Thank you so much!